# Sizing SmartGWT Window based on contents

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

I'm trying to get a `SmartGWT Window` sizing based on its contents.

The correct way of adding elements to a Window it's through the `addItem` method.

So, when I run this code, the Window do not get resized. However, if I add the Label through `addMember` the resizing works fine but this break the Window appearance

```
Window window = new Window();
window.setOverflow(Overflow.VISIBLE);

window.addItem(new Label("aaaaaaaa"));
window.addItem(new Label("aaaaaaaa"));
window.addItem(new Label("aaaaaaaa"));
window.addItem(new Label("aaaaaaaa"));
window.addItem(new Label("aaaaaaaa"));
window.show();
```

Any ideas ?

*Using SmartGWT 2.5*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I missed the AutoSize property... Works as expected

```
window.setAutoSize(true);
```